# SQL Auto Job Email Notification with Dynamic Table and Hyperlnks

Tags: sql, email

I have an auto job in Sql that goes out and gets a dataset, and I input it into an email using the following code.  My dilemma right now, is that the 'Link' column is showing the ENTIRE link text.  I only want to show the test of the result value, as a hyperlink.  For simplicity purposes, I have only included the code that gets my bodyText:

```
SET @tableCastings = 
N'<H3>Missing Timestamps Report </H3>' +
N'<table border="1" cellspacing="5" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Estrangelo Edessa, Verdana; border: Solid 1px #666666; border-collapse: collapse; color: Black;">' +
N'<tr  style=" background-color: #EEDC82; color: Black; font-weight: bold;"><th>Pattern</th><th> Rev </th><th> CastingID </th><th>Serial</th><th>Link</th><th> LastOp </th><th>Date </th><th> Missing Op </th>'+
CAST (( SELECT td = temp2.var3, '', 
td = temp2.var4, '',
td = temp2.var2, '',
td = temp2.var5, '', 
td = CAST(url.com/page.aspx?var1='  AS XML),   temp2.var1,'&var2=',temp2.var2,'&var3=',temp2.var3,'',
td = temp2.var6, '',
td = temp2.var7, '',
td = temp2.var8, ''
FROM HTTEMPPL51 temp2 
 FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) +

N'</table><br><br>'
```

This gets me the email desired, it's just looking a bit bulky due to the hyperlink text.  And leads?